# Web Essentials element content HTML autocompletion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, material-design, web-essentials

I'm trying to implement autocompletion for Google's Material Design icons in Web Essentials.

This icon font uses the element content instead of the class attribute to define the icon like this: `<i class="material-icons">add</i>`.

I've been examining the HTML completion classes currently existing and have come up with the code below, but for some reason this isn't working.

Any help on pointing me in the right direction, as I've been unable to find documentation on these assemblies, would be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.Html.Editor.Completion.Def;
using Microsoft.Web.Core.ContentTypes;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using Microsoft.Html.Editor.Completion;

namespace MaterialIcons
{
    [HtmlCompletionProvider(CompletionTypes.Children)]
    [ContentType(HtmlContentTypeDefinition.HtmlContentType)]
    class IconCompletion : IHtmlCompletionListProvider
    {
        private static List<string> _icons = new List<string>()
        {
            "info_outline",
            "input",
            "invert_colors"
        };

        public string CompletionType
        {
            get
            {
                return CompletionTypes.Children;
            }
        }

        public IList<HtmlCompletion> GetEntries(HtmlCompletionContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Element.GetAttribute("class").Value.Contains("material-icons"))
            {
                return new List<HtmlCompletion>();
            }
            return CreateCompletionItems(context).ToArray();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<HtmlCompletion> CreateCompletionItems(HtmlCompletionContext context)
        {
            foreach (string item in _icons)
            {
                yield return new SimpleHtmlCompletion(item, context.Session) {  };
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I needed to supply an element for the provider.

So instead of `[HtmlCompletionProvider(CompletionTypes.Children)]` I had to enter `[HtmlCompletionProvider(CompletionTypes.Children, "*")]` to apply my provider to all HTML elements.